# how to install causalml packages

Tags: python, c++, windows, spyder

windows 10
IDE:Spyder
Python 3.7.9
I failed to install this package and the error in cmd is shown as follow:

> python setup.py install running install running bdist_egg running
> egg_info writing causalml.egg-info\PKG-INFO writing dependency_links
> to causalml.egg-info\dependency_links.txt writing requirements to
> causalml.egg-info\requires.txt writing top-level names to
> causalml.egg-info\top_level.txt reading manifest file
> 'causalml.egg-info\SOURCES.txt' reading manifest template
> 'MANIFEST.in' warning: no files found matching '.pxd' under directory
> 'causalml' warning: no files found matching '.h' under directory
> 'causalml' adding license file 'LICENSE' writing manifest file
> 'causalml.egg-info\SOURCES.txt' installing library code to
> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg running install_lib running build_py running
> build_ext building 'causalml.inference.tree.causaltree' extension
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe
> /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD
> -IC:\Users\absence\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\numpy\core\include
> -IC:\Users\absence\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\numpy\core\include
> -IC:\Users\absence\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\Python\include -IC:\Users\absence\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\Python\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt"
> /Tccausalml/inference/tree/causaltree.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\causalml/inference/tree/causaltree.obj
> -O3 causaltree.c causalml/inference/tree/causaltree.c(31): fatal error C1083: “Python.h”: No such file or directory error: command
> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe'
> failed with exit status 2

May I ask a help for how to solve it?

Comment: Maybe, it's better to raise an issue where you did this download from. I believe the essence is `fatal error C1083: “Python.h”`. `Python.h` is the header of the C-Python API. Maybe, it's simply missing. Maybe, you are required to install something else as prerequisite. Maybe, there is simply a bug (a missing include path) somewhere in the build files of that package... (To be clear: A Python interpreter is fully sufficient to execute Python code. If you want to extend it by modules (wrapping libraries) compiled from C, you need a C-Python API _additionally_.)